# How to extract the session id from an RTSP message's content?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string like this:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Server: Ants Rtsp Server/1.0
Date: 21 Oct 2016 15:55:30 GMT
Session: 980603187; timeout=60
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;ssrc=F006B800
```

I want to extract the session number(`980603187`)

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: do you already have this converted to a string or you want to convert to string and then extract session information?

Comment: Check javadoc for String class, esp look for `substring` and `indexOf` methods.

Comment: Yes i have already converted to a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a `regular expression` with a group, then extract the value of the group as next:

```
String content ="RTSP/1.0 200 OK\n" +
   "CSeq: 3\n" +
   "Server: Ants Rtsp Server/1.0\n" +
   "Date: 21 Oct 2016 15:55:30 GMT\n" +
   "Session: 980603187; timeout=60\n" +
   "Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;ssrc=F006B800\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Session: ([a-zA-Z0-9$\\-_.+]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
980603187
```

**Explanation:**

```
Session: ([a-zA-Z0-9$\\-_.+]+)
```

- `Session:`  matches the characters `Session:`  literally (case sensitive)
- `([a-zA-Z0-9$\\-_.+]+)`: Capturing group that matches with several consecutive ALPHA, DIGIT or SAFE characters (at least one) (cf [RFC 2326 chapter 3.4 Session Identifiers](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt))

Comment: 12 seconds faster. Does it matter? xD

Comment: Yep, because you made a mistake; according to RFC 2326 the `";"` is only present when the *optional* timeout is present.

Comment: Ah okay ! Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex! Having `String str = ..`, extract the number needed with the Regex capturing anything between `Session:` and `;`:

```
Session: (.+);
```

Feel free to specify only letters `\\w+` or digits `\\d+`. Mind the double escaping in Java. The first matched `m.group(1)` is your result:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Session: (.+);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Outputs `980603187`. Check out the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bQgEcx/3) for the explanation.

---

In come cases the `; timeout` is optional and to need to amend the Regex used:

```
Session: (.+?)[\n;]
```

Comment: Wrong, the timeout and therefore `';'` are optional.

Comment: Well, OP haven't said anythong about that. Moreover I am not familiar with  RFC 2326 standard. However I can include it to the answer.

Comment: Well, that's what you get for not reading the standard. I hadn't used it before either, but I looked it up in the mean time. This is how you get brittle code.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have each header you can look up the specification in [RFC 2336](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) which specifies the RTSP protocol.

First of all, you should split your string into lines. The lines end with CR/LF according to the specification. The first line indicates the response, the other should be header fields.

The definition is:

```
 Session  = "Session" ":" session-id [ ";" "timeout" "=" delta-seconds ]
```

where `session-id` is specified as:

```
 session-id   =   1*( ALPHA | DIGIT | safe )
```

which means you should not confuse it with a number. The definition of safe is

```
   safe               =  "\$" | "-" | "_" | "." | "+"
```

and alpha means all upper- and lowercase numbers. This means it is possible to put in a base 64 url encoded binary session-id, by the way.

OK, now it becomes a question of looking for the session ID. You step through all lines (except the first one) and then look for the line that matches:

```
   ^Session[ \t]*:[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9\$\-_.+]+).*$
```

this will match only valid session headers / valid session identifiers. Note that the standard is vague about white-space, so I skipped over space and tab characters before and after the colon ':'. The session identifier is then in group 1 of the regular expression.

You can of course easily extend this by including the timeout in the regular expression, once you need it.

---

Note that you will have to double escape the backslash characters before using the regular expression in Java. It's also possible to use the Posix character classes defined in the `Pattern` class to make the regular expression more readable.

Comment: Wrote this answer to create a general method of handling this by *starting to read the standard*.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache-commons in your dependencies, then you can do it within one line:

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(string, "Session: ", ";");
```